# How can I create a vector by only using for loop? (vector is specified in the body)

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...,n,...,n)

I want to make the above vector by for loop, but not using rep function or the other functions. This may not be good question to ask in stackoverflow, but since I am a newbie for R, I dare ask here to be helped.

(You can suppose the length of the vector is 10)

Comment: what functions can be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `for` loop, it can be done with

```
n <- 10
out <- c()
for(i in seq_len(n)){
      for(j in seq_len(i)) {                   
         out <- c(out, i)
           }                  

}
```

In `R`, otherwise, this can be done as

```
rep(seq_len(n), seq_len(n))
```

Comment: I suppose OP is asking this for a homework or something related to school but is there any practical reasons why someone would use a for loop instead of ``rep()`` and ``seq()`` speedwise?

Comment: @Gainz May be to understand how it can be done in a loop.

Comment: @Gainz Just wonder how it operates. Since I came from other language, rep() kinds of functions are new to me and wanted to know in loops to understand better ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give you a few hints *if using `rep` would have been possible* which may help you with R in general. (Without `rep` usage, just look at @akrun)

**Short answer** using `rep`

```
rep(1:n, 1:n)
```

**Long Answer** using `rep`

First of all, we should try to have a look at official sources:

- [R-project "getting help"](https://www.r-project.org/help.html), here you can see the standard way to get a function's documentation is just typing `?func_name` in your R console
- [R-project "official manuals"](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) offer a good introduction to R. Try looking at the first topic, ["An Introduction to R"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)

From the previous two (and other sources as well) you will find two interesting functions:

- `:` operator: it can be used to generate a sequence of integers from `a` to `b` like `a:b`. Typing `1:3`, for instance, gives you the `1, 2, 3` vector
- `rep(x, t)` is a function  which can be used to replicate the item(s) `x` `t` times.

You also need to know R is "vector-oriented", that is it applies functions over vectors without you typing explicits loops.
For instance, if you call `repl(1:3, 2)`, it's (almost) equivalent to running:

```
for(i in 1:3)
    rep(i, 2)
```

By combining the previous two functions and the notion R is "vector-oriented", you get the `rep(1:n, 1:n)` solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't want to use `rep`, but here is a method of not using it or any functions similar to `rep` within the loop.

```
`for (i in 1:10){
  a<-NA
  a[1:i] <- i
  if (i==1){b<-a}
  else if (i >1){b <- c(b,a)}
  assign("OutputVector",b,envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }`
`OutputVector`
```

Going for an n of ten seemed subjective so I just did the loop for numbers 1 through 10 and you can take the first 10 numbers in the vector if you want. `OutputVector[1:10]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single loop, though it's a `while` rather than a `for`

```r
n <- 10
x <- 1; 
i <- 2; 

while(i <= n) 
{
 x <- c(x, 1/i); 
 if(sum(x) %% 1 == 0) i = i + 1; 
}

1/x
```