# How to manually write a function which duplicates values in r?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am learning how to do loops now, and trying to figure out how to write a function which duplicates arguments manually.

Essentially, I want to take something like this:

```
duplicate_easy <- function(x){
  rep(c(x), c(x))
}

x1 <- c(3,1,9)

duplicate_easy(x1)
```

result: 3 3 3, 1, 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

And replace it with a for loop along the lines of,

```
duplicate <- function(x)
  {

  result <- NULL
  for (i in rep(x) )
    {
    result <- c(result, rep(x))
  }
  return(result)
}

x1 <- c(3, 1, 9)

duplicate(x1)
```

Which is also intended to result in the same thing, but the above does not work.

Comment: Possible. duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176243/how-can-i-create-a-vector-by-only-using-for-loop-vector-is-specified-in-the-bo/60176313#60176313

Comment: I don't understand do you want to use the "rep()" function or are you trying to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
duplicate <- function(x)
{

  result <- NULL
  for (i in 1:length(x))
  {
    result <- c(result, rep(x[i], x[i]))
  }
  return(result)
}
```